# Facebook HTML5 Like Button on AJAX Pages?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, html, facebook-like

I'm looking for a way to make the Facebook **HTML5** Like Button work on my Ajax views.

**On my homepage**, I call:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={myappid}";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**In my view head**, I have included the Facebook-Meta-Tags (working properly according to OG-Debugger):

```
og:url / og:title / og:image / og:description / fb:app_id / fb:admins / og:type
```

**In the view content**, I have the like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.de/view/<?php echo $viewslug; ?>" data-width="400" data-height="50" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

The button is not rendered in the view.

Does anybody have a solution ?

**I explictly want to use the HTML5 button and not the Iframe nor XFBML buttons?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the links provided by the earlier answer, I found a Jquery implementation.

Maybe it helps others:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/

**UPDATE:**

Just found **Socialite JS** as a better way (as I also want to use Google+ and Twitter):

( http://socialitejs.com/ || https://github.com/tmort/Socialite )

Comment: you really should not use jquery for all things...vanilla js is better in most cases. and i suggest not using those social plugins, they come with a lot of overhead are not as flexible as custom code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use this to parse the Social Plugins, right after loading the AJAX content:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Make sure the JavaScript SDK is loaded before using AJAX, it´s best to use this code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Right where it says "Additional initialization code" you can use AJAX, that´s when the JavaScript SDK will be loaded.

Comment: it will work 100% if used correctly, can you publish the ajax code`and where you tried using the function?

Comment: one possible problem: you are using ajax right on page load, and the javascript sdk is not loaded yet. there should be an error in the browser console then.

Comment: i´ve added more info, maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I ended up using the Jquery soltuion for the sdk call. Voted up for your help